# create a multidimensional array from mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

i would like to create a array of 3 dimensions from 3 mysql tables(sections/rubriques/category):

```
[0]  section_title_1
      [0] rubrique_title_1
           [0] category_title_1
           [1] category_title_2
           [2] category_title_3
      [1] rubrique_title_2
            ...................

[1]  section_title_2
      .........
```

here is my code:

```
$output = array();

$i = 0;
$sections=$this->_model->get_table_sections();

foreach($sections as $section){
output[$i] = $section->section_title;

  $ii = 0;
  $rubriques =  $this->_model->get_rubriques_for_a_section($section-   >section_id);

    foreach($rubriques as $rubrique){ 
    $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii] = $rubrique->rubrique_title;

    $iii = 0;
    $categories =  $this->_model->get_categ_for_a_section_and_a_rubrique($section->section_id,$rubrique->rubrique_id);
         foreach($categories as $categorie){
         $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii]['categories'][$iii] = $categorie->categorie_title;
         $iii++;
                                           }
  $ii++;
                               }
  $i++;
                          }

            var_dump($output);
```

at the statement  : $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii] = $rubrique->rubrique_title;

```
i get an error of Illegal string offset 'rubr'
```

Can you give me the answer of this coding ?

Many thanks..

Comment: Change this `output[$i] = $section->section_title;` to this `output[$i]['section_title'] = $section->section_title;`.. the thing is you are trying access string as an array here `$output[$i]['rubr']` - this is just a clue, you have to change rest of your code too..

Comment: ok for the section part but after for rubrique ?

Comment: maybe $output[$i]['section_title'][$ii] = $rubrique->rubrique_title;

Comment: can you give me the entire code , please

Answer (score 0):

you getting error because `$output[$i]` is undefined and has no *prototype* of *Array*. So, you can solve it by initializing it as empty array like this:

`$output[$i] = array();`

But, you till have error, this code solve your problem:

```
$output = array();

$i = 0;
$sections=$this->_model->get_table_sections();

foreach($sections as $section){
    $output[$i]['title'] = $section->section_title;

  $ii = 0;
  $rubriques =  $this->_model->get_rubriques_for_a_section($section-   >section_id);

    foreach($rubriques as $rubrique){ 
    $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii] = $rubrique->rubrique_title;

    $iii = 0;
    $categories =  $this->_model->get_categ_for_a_section_and_a_rubrique($section->section_id,$rubrique->rubrique_id);
         foreach($categories as $categorie){
         $output[$i] = isset( $output[$i] ) ? $output[$i] : array();
         $output[$i]['rubr'] = isset( $output[$i]['rubr'] ) ? $output[$i]['rubr'] : array();
         $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii] = isset( $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii] ) ? $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii] : array();
         $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii]['categories'] = isset( $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii]['categories'] ) ? $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii]['categories'] : array();
         $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii]['categories'][$iii] = isset( $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii]['categories'][$iii] ) ? $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii]['categories'][$iii] : array();
         $output[$i]['rubr'][$ii]['categories'][$iii] = $categorie->categorie_title;
         $iii++;
                                           }
  $ii++;
                               }
  $i++;
                          }

            var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the way:

```
$output = array();
$sections = $this->_model->get_table_sections();

foreach($sections as $section){
    $output[$section->section_title] = array();

    $rubriques = $this->_model->get_rubriques_for_a_section($section->section_id);

    foreach($rubriques as $rubrique){
        $output[$section->section_title][$rubrique->rubrique_title] = array();

        $categories =  $this->_model->get_categ_for_a_section_and_a_rubrique($section->section_id,$rubrique->rubrique_id);
        foreach($categories as $categorie){
            $output[$section->section_title][$rubrique->rubrique_title][] = $categorie->categorie_title;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Use titles as indexes. Of course only if you don't need numeric indexes, but from your code I suppose you don't.

Comment: thanks  David  how can i get  the numeric indexes ( $section->id,$rubrique->id,$categorie->id)  ??  thanks

Comment: Instead of `$section->section_title` just use `$section->id` if the property `id` exists in yours objects

Comment: ok   i should code as   $output[$section->section_title][$rubrique->rubrique_title] = array("rubrique id" => $rubrique->rubrique_id);                                                                                                                                but how for the last  item (category)  ??  $output[$section->section_title][$rubrique->rubrique_title][] = $categorie->categorie_title;                          maybe :$output[$section->section_title][$rubrique->rubrique_title][$categorie->categorie_title] = $categorie->id;   thanks

Comment: No - use IDs as indexes (keys). As I described above. So instead of `$output[$section->section_title] = array();` you should have `$output[$section->section_id] = array();` and so on...

Comment: i would like to have:                example:
         Agriculture (=section title)   
        section:1    (=section id)   
            Elevage       (=rubrique title)   
            rubrique:1  (=rubrique id)   
                Materiel       (=category title)    
                categorie:1  (=categorie id)    
                Pneus    
                categorie:2                            THANKS

Comment: i am searching for the category level:          foreach($sections as $section){
    $output[$section->section_title] = array("section id" => $section->section_id);
      foreach($rubriques as $rubrique){
        $output[$section->section_title][$rubrique->rubrique_title] = array("rubrique id" => $rubrique->rubrique_id);
        foreach($categories as $categorie){
          $output[$section->section_title][$rubrique->rubrique_title][[$categorie->categorie_title]] = ????????????

Comment: David,   i have created a more clear post of my question at :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538533/multidimensional-associative-array-with-id   thanks for your support